# Tasseled Cap Transformation Rapid Eye

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, satellite

I want to do tasseled cap transformation on rapid eye data. the main question would be about the parameters which are used. Somebody has a suggestion?

---

A short update concerning this attempt to calculate Tasseled Cap transformation.
After investigating in this area from my point of view, the result of a TC calculation for Rapid Eye will be not sufficent, because of simple reasons. Calculating the 6 TC image (Brightness, Wetness, Greenness, Fourth, Fifth and Sixth) is in Landsat obviously based on 6 Bands (1,2,3,4,5,7). It is possible to use the thermal band but most publications do not consider it. Rapid Eyes "highest" band in that way is NIR which is not really the decisive factor. To calculate Rapid Eyes TC are definitively needed 2 more bands above the red-edge band of Rapid Eye. It possible but i believe it would not make so much sense.

Comment: This is absolutely not the case! The TC transformation is an orthogonal PCA transformation where the data is rotated to represent the BGW bands along with any noise remaining. All you have to do is figure out the coefficients that will transform the data into the TC PCA space. The QuickBird and RapidEye have almost identical wavelengths in the R,G,B,NIR bands so, the published methodology is applicable. You are confused over the overall transformation where all bands are rotated. In the case of Landsat some of bands are rotated into noise whereas this is not the case with these other sensors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are published coefficients available for MSS, TM5 ETM+7, QuickBird and IKONOS but I do not believe that anybody has derived coefficients for Rapid Eye. Here is a paper that describes how the authors derived the coefficients for Quickbird (http://www.asprs.org/a/publications/proceedings/pecora16/Yarbrough_L.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are Tasseled Cap Coefficients for the RapidEye sensors available: Brightness, Greenness and Yellowness. Yellowness - instead of the commonly derived Wetness  (e.g. Landsat) - was derived because the RapidEye sensors do not have SWIR bands (SWIR bands respond to moisture variation, e.g. in soil/vegetation). Yellowness instead shows the variation of dry, senecent crops, a result of chlorophyll breakdown and cell structure decomposition.

see:

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Horst_Weichelt/publication/270302804_Derivation_of_Tasseled_Cap_Coefficients_for_RapidEye_data/links/551aa9d20cf2bb754076a8eb.pdf][1]

http://www.int-arch-photogramm-remote-sens-spatial-inf-sci.net/XL-7-W3/101/2015/isprsarchives-XL-7-W3-101-2015.pdf][2]

Answer (score 1):

I just found a [proceeding paper by Maurice Schönert et al. (2014)](http://spie.org/Publications/Proceedings/Paper/10.1117/12.2066842) in which they derive Tasseled Cap Coefficients for the RapidEye sensors. I haven't tested it myself, but it looks promising.